# Scoring in Python game does not work

Tags: python, function, variables, syntax, global

I am new to Python, trying to pick up the language outside of my school courses. This Rock Paper Scissors game I am working on functions correctly, although the score output does not show anything. Here is the code...

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python2

# Extra modules used
import random
import time

# Set each move to a specific number
# Once a selection is made by the player,
# it will be equated to that specific variable.
rock = 1
paper = 2
scissors = 3

# Text representation of each move
names = { rock: "Rock", paper: "Paper", scissors: "Scissors" }

# Game Rules
rules = { rock: scissors, paper: rock, scissors: paper }

# Declare variables to be used to track scoring
player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

# Function to print a greeting and start
# a loop to allow the player to continue
#playing as many times as they wish
def start():
    print ("Let's play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
    while game():
        pass # Allows the loop to stop when player is done
    scores() # Call function when done playing

def game():
    # Call move function to determine player move
    player = move()
    # Get computer move as random int between 1 and 3
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    # Send the move through the result function
    result(player, computer)
    return play_again()

# Function to obtain a move from the player
def move():
    while True:
        print
        player = input("Rock = 1\nPaper = 2\nScissors = 3\nMake a move: ")
        # Try to set the player move, or catch the error
        try:
            # Cast the user input as an integer
            player = int(player)
            # If entry is valid, set the variable
            if player in (1,2,3):
                return player
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print ("Oops! I didn't understand that. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.")

# Function to determine the result of the game
# player move and computer move are passed in
def result(player, computer):
    # Countdown to result display
    print ("1...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    # Display the computer's move
    # string.format() gets the text version
    # of the move and inserts it where "0"
    print ("Computer threw {0}!".format(names[computer]))
    #Call the scores set earlier
    global player_score, computer_score
    # Check the results of the game
    if player == computer:
        print ("Tie game.")
    # Check if the losing move to the player's move
    # is equal to the computer's move
    elif rules[player] == computer:
        print ("Your victory has been assured.")
        player_score += 1
    else:
        print ("The computer laughs as you realize you have been defeated.")
        computer_score += 1

# Ask to play again
def play_again():
    answer = input("Would you like to play again? y/n: ")
    if answer in ("y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "Of course!"):
        return answer
    else:
        print ("Thank you very much for playing. See you next time!")

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print ("HIGH SCORES")
    print ("Player: "), player_score
    print ("Computer: "), computer_score

# Used to execute in command line or import
# into another Python script. This will prevent
# the code from being executed when being imported.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: This works fine for me, whether I exit the game and look at the final scores, or whether I call `scores()` on each iteration of whether I would like to play again. I cannot reproduce the issue in 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print` statements are a little off.
You should be including the arguments inside the `print` statement

`print("Player: ", player_score)`

**Edit:**
To speak a little more to printing. You could also use
`print("Player: {}".format(player_score))`

Comment: Is this with Python 3? Works fine on Python 2.7 with the brackets, I cannot find the problem, but I think they're required with 3.x `print`?

Comment: Thank you for the help, this works, and I see the difference now!

Comment: I am using Python 3.5, but the code projects I am working with utilize Python 2.7

Comment: `print` as a statement is python3 (py2 with futures).

Answer (score 1):

You need the variables inside the brackets so:

`print ("Player: "), player_score
    print ("Computer: "), computer_score`

becomes

```
print ("Player: ", player_score)
print ("Computer: ", computer_score)
```

Alternatively,

```
print ("Player: {}".format(player_score))
print ("Computer: {}".format(computer_score))
```

Format is better to use as there is a whole lot more you can do with it (I'll let you find that out for yourself)!